# One time Script in batches - Developer Console

Tags: apex, batch, execute-anonymous

I wrote a script to update a field value on several thousand records based on certain criteria. I will only be doing this one time, and that's the  reason for not putting the logic in an Apex Class.

I tried running the script in Developer Console and ran into the classic 'Too many query records 50001' error.

I can put the logic in Batch Class, but that would mean writing a test class, and deploying the two classes to production. And after my records are updated , i will not be using this Batch Class again.

My question is -

How can i run the script to update records in Batches to avoid the 50001 error?
Is limiting the SOQL to 5000 and running the script manually many time is my only option?

Comment: `running the script manually many time is my only option` - I've done that many times for these 1 time operations

Comment: Running the script over Anonymous Apex in a loop from a local script would also be an option (could do it in shell with SFDX or in Python)

Comment: I've marked this question as a duplicate for a solution you can reuse over and again, and it even comes as an installable package. Please feel free to comment back if you have any questions.

Comment: Glad to get confirmation from cropredy that this is an option for 1 time scripts. i will install the package in sandbox and test. If i have follow up questions on @sfdcfox solution i will ask. I don't have the depth to understand David's solution at this moment. one day, i hope i do.